# Why can't I pass a bound member function as a callable?

Tags: c++

This code is a compile error:

```
std::string str("hello world"); 
std::unordered_set filter{'h', 'w', ' '};
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), filter.count), str.end());
```

I know this can be done with a lambda, but why is it not allowed like this? Works fine in Java.

Comment: You should remove the "works fine in Java" part as that is not useful information. It doesn't work in cheese either. Different things work in different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I pass a bound member function as a callable?

You *can* pass a bound member function as callable.

It's just that member access operator (`.`) does not bind the object to the function and return bound one.

You can bind a member function (pointer) using `std::bind`:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    std::bind(&std::unordered_set<char>::count, filter, _1))
```

Although, this isn't any "better" than using a lambda.

Comment: Isn't the question _why_ the dot operator syntax doesn't work in this way? It would be a pretty handy, compact and intuitive way to bind member functions to objects. And it wouldn't be the first time a symbol has been used to mean different things in different contexts in C++.

Comment: `unordered_set` requires template parameters.

Comment: @user2079303 you also you forgot the placeholder `_1` for the actual function parameter

Comment: @Jans also fixed. You may be able to tell that I don't really use `std::bind` much :)

Comment: @juanchopanza well, that question might be pointless to ask here, and might be better directed at committee / Bjarne. C++ is the way it is because the standard says so. The standard says whatever it does because the committee has decided so. The first standard didn't even have `std::bind`, so presumably argument binding wasn't in the scope of the design of the language initially. It hasn't been added because there hasn't been proposal to add it, (or because such proposal has been rejected in which case there would be a good answer, but I haven't seen such proposal).

Comment: @user2079303 There might actually be people who know the answer. What is pointless is posting non-answers.

Comment: But yeah, the answer might well be a disappointing "nobody thought of it originally, and then nobody has made a serious proposal about it".

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't work that way. You need to explicitly specify object for method to be called from, using [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    std::string str("hello world"); 
    std::unordered_set<char> filter{'h', 'w', ' '};
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::bind(&std::unordered_set<char>::count, &filter, _1)), str.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that C++20 introduces `std::bind_front` which is a bit simpler:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::bind_front(&std::unordered_set<char>::count, filter)), str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter.count` is not a **function pointer**, and thus can't be passed as argument.

You can do it using [lambda (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to capture `filter` and **forward** the arguments to the member function `count`.

```
std::string str("hello world"); 
std::unordered_set filter{'h', 'w', ' '};    
str.erase(
    std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](auto &each) noexcept {
        return filter.count(each);
    }), str.end());
```